# How to automatically close an alert after a certain time React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, alert

I would like to automatically close an alert after a couple of seconds without having the user do it themselves.

If possible I would like to do this using Alert (not AlertIOS), but if only AlertIOS has it then I guess I have no other choice.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you considered using a modal? this would let you control it using a setTimeout() call once it is displayed...

Comment: I have never used a modal, can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Also, how do I even dismiss it myself? In the documentation there is no method to dismiss the alert using code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use Modal component

```
<Modal
  animationType={"slide"}
  transparent={false}
  visible={this.state.modalVisible}></Modal>
```

So you can call setTimeout() in your function to update the state variable modalVisible to show / hide it. More examples can be found here from the official doc (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html)